# Entities - text to number in DialogFlow

Tags: python, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

my DialogFlow bot receives messages something like that:

```
10k 
5k 
15 k
10kk
5 dozens
```

etc

How I can set up my entities to convert it in current number (10000, 5000, 15000, 10000000, 60)?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** OP was looking for a Python solution. But for anyone who came here and need a node solution, then you can use the answer below.

Try using the NPM library [numbro](https://www.npmjs.com/package/numbro).

```
> numbro.unformat('10k')
10000
> numbro.unformat('5k')
5000
> numbro.unformat('15 k')
15000
> numbro.unformat('10kk')
10000000
> numbro.unformat('5 dozens')
undefined
>
```

The "dozens" example doesn't seem to work. But you're 90% on the way and can probably just implement something simple to cover the cornercases (or contribute to the library to add support).

Comment: Ah, I assumed that you were working with node :-) Updated your post with a Python tag.